# Android Dark Theme - Best way to implements dark theme on application

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

I've added dark theme support for my application using 2 different themes declared in `styles.xml`.

On official android developer site:

> In order to support Dark theme, you must set your app's theme (usually
>   found in res/values/styles.xml) to inherit from a DayNight theme

and this is what I've done. I've also created `colors-night.xml` to avoid modifying colors that cannot be modified in `styles.xml` by coding and this works too: when dark mode is activated from device system, colors changes automatically.

At this point, I was wondering which is the best way to implements dark theme: creating 2 different themes, using colors-night (and drawable-night) or a combination of these 2 ways?

Answer (score 1):

First up is the youtube video below pretty much tells you what the current best practices are with regards to theming.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Owkf8DhAOSo

They talked about splitting your styles into

- `themes.xml` -> theme related styles
- `styles.xml` -> component related styles
- `type.xml` -> text appearances styles

All your colors should then be in one colors.xml which lives in `values`.

You will then have the following structure:

- values/themes.xml
- values/colors.xml
- values/type.xml
- values/styles.xml
- values-night/themes.xml

In practice, I find that it is still hard to contain all the colors in just one `colors.xml`. I still create `values-night/colors.xml` as some colors don't necessarily fall into a style.

See this in practice in this repo. Observer that Google themselves didn't follow their point on just using one `colors.xml`.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/material-theme-builder

Comment: Haha, you cannot believe it, my first story in the new position is to implement the dark theme!  I followed this which is pretty easy to go: https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/DarkTheme